# Linear hypothesis test for multivariate linear model (`mlm` object) in R

Tags: r, multivariate-regression, multilevel-analysis

I'm running a mulivariate linear model like this one:

```
set.seed(1)
X1 <- runif(100)
X2 <- rnorm(100)
Y1 <- X1*5+X2+rnorm(100, sd=0.3)
Y2 <- X1+X2+rnorm(100, sd=0.3)
 
lm(cbind(Y1,Y2)~X1+X2)

Call:
lm(formula = cbind(Y1, Y2) ~ X1 + X2)

Coefficients:
             Y1        Y2      
(Intercept)  0.03915  0.14063
X1           4.93832  0.78631
X2           1.02129  0.99749
```

and I'd like to compare impact one of my IVs (`X2` for example) on two of my DVs. In other words, I'd like to test if *regression parameter for X2 and Y1* is statistically different from *regression parameter for X2 and Y2*.

I believe it could be some clever call of `car::linearHypothesis()`. Any help appreciated.

PS. `multcomp::glht()` does not work on `mlm` objects produced by `lm(cbind(...)~...)` since `coef.mlm()` function throws a matrix (not a vector as required by `multcomp::glht()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regression parameter for X2 and Y1 was statistically different from regression parameter for X2 and Y2, then regression parameter for X2 and Y1-Y2 would be statistically different from 0, so a "clever call" to `car::linearHypothesis` uses a matrix of linear transformation of outcomes (called `P`) like this:

```
linearHypothesis(mod, 
                 hypothesis.matrix = c(0,0,1), 
                 P = matrix(c(1,-1))
)

 Response transformation matrix:
   [,1]
Y1    1
Y2   -1

Sum of squares and products for the hypothesis:
           [,1]
[1,] 0.04916393

Sum of squares and products for error:
         [,1]
[1,] 18.40802

Multivariate Tests: 
                 Df test stat  approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)
Pillai            1 0.0026637 0.2590665      1     97 0.61192
Wilks             1 0.9973363 0.2590665      1     97 0.61192
Hotelling-Lawley  1 0.0026708 0.2590665      1     97 0.61192
Roy               1 0.0026708 0.2590665      1     97 0.61192
```